# Laravel two web site one auth

Tags: laravel

How do I link two pages to work under one database so when a user logs on to one page, the user is also logged on to the other domain?

Comment: Just to clarify: you have two laravel apps and you want to authorize users in both apps using same users table? Are both apps using subdomains of one domain?

Comment: I have two domains and on each of them laravel applications ....
Signing in and registering will be on one domain, but when the user logs on one will be automatically and the other logged on

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible and here is why: when user authorizes, server creates and stores the session, then server sends to clients browser the response with session id via `Cookies` http header. Cookies for each domain can not be shared because of security policy.

So you can craete session for first domain, share it between domains using tricky handlers, but eventually session id will be stored in cookies by client for only first domain. On the second domain the user will not be authorized because he does not have the session id stored by browser.

Perhaps you could elaborate more about your use case to find a simplier solution.

Update: cookies can be shared between two subdomains from one domain. And in this case the task can be solved.

Comment: But I do not know how